# Will this reference become invalid?

Tags: c++, reference, lifetime

I am trying to understand reference.
So given the following program...

```
void Foo(std::string& m)
{
    std::string f = "Foo Stack Content"; 
    m = f;
}

int main()
{
    std::string m = "Main Stack Content";
    Foo(m);

    std::cout << m << std::endl;
}
```

Since m is assigned f in Foo, and f is created on the stack in Foo, when Foo exits, f and the memory it points to won't be valid anymore.  Does that mean that m is also invalid now?

Comment: You didn't assign a reference. You assigned a value (and copy-assigned a `std::string` in the process). Once bound, you can't change a reference.

Comment: That's not how it works, your reference remains valid because string f is copied into string m that was passed to Foo by reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In c++ `class`, operators can have `different` meanings depending on the way they were defined(overloaded). In your case `m` is a reference and `f` is variable. The expression `m = f` is an assignment between two class objects(well references are not exactly objects but `alias`). `std::string` performs a `deep copy` between `m` and `f`. That means that the values of `f` are copied to `m`. You should also keep in mind that there is a fundamental difference between a pointer and a reference. Pointers are real variables that are stored in memory. References are `alias`, they are the same variable with a different name

Comment: @hvd is it more clear now ? Thank you for your comment

Comment: So as another example, if I have a different class instead of the string class that doesn't overloads the = operator, m would becomes invalid?

Comment: @StackOverflowUser it depends on how the class definition. If, for example, the string class consists of `char* ` which are dynamically allocated on the heap then yes there will be a problem because the copy will be a `shallow copy` (since the overload assignment operator is not defined) . `shallow copy` is a pointer copy, once the object goes out of scope and the `destructor` is called the pointers will point to an invalid memory location (undefined behavior)

Comment: Pointers and references are exactly the same thing, only different syntax.

Comment: Thank you.  I understand now.

Comment: @RustyX no they are not, pointer has a valid memory location, references do not. If `a` is a reference to `b` then `a` is just an `alias` of b. `a` does not `reside` in memory. If `a` is a pointer to `b` it exists in a memory location.